# UWP MapControl Latitude doesn't update

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I started working with UWP MapControl, and I'm testing the MapTapped event method. I created two textblocks and they are updated when the MapTapped event is triggered, updating their contents with the "tapped" latitude and longitude.

The longitude is updating perfectly, but the latitude gets stuck in a really small value, no updating at all after the first click.

[UWP MapControl Printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HPB3.jpg)

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3933332)

Answer (score 0):

In your code you're doing

```
    tblock_latitude.Text = args.Location.Position.Altitude.ToString()
```

so your latitude variable is being assigned to that location's **altitude**, which doesn't change much.

Change to

```
    tblock_latitude.Text = args.Location.Position.Latitude.ToString()
```

and you'll get the right behavior.